# Skip arguments in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this:

```
function foo(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
}
```

In order to call this function only with an `f` argument, I know I should do:

```
foo(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, theFValue);
```

Is there a less verbose way to do this?

Comment: Is the function written by you? Can you change it?

Comment: You could use a single custom object as parameter instead a list of different parameters.

Comment: @Juhana  Yes, is my own function

Comment: @Serge, **The answer is here:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622678/632951

Comment: FWIW, The `var _ = undefined; foo(_,_,_,_,_, theFValue);` solution is buried in [this long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32518672/199364). You would of course do the initial declaration of `_` *once*, in some common utility file that you include in every js file.

Comment: I could have sworn you could just do foo( , , , , , fValue); but I see that it is not possible.

Answer (score 82):

Such:

```
foo(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, arg1, arg2);
```

.is equal to:

```
foo(...Array(5), arg1, arg2);
```

.or:

```
foo(...[,,,,,], arg1, arg2);
```

---

Such:

```
foo(undefined, arg1, arg2);
```

.is equal to:

```
foo(...Array(1), arg1, arg2);
```

.or:

```
foo(...[,], arg1, arg2);
```

---

Such:

```
foo(arg1, arg2);
```

.is equal to:

```
foo(...Array(0), arg1, arg2);
```

.or:

```
foo(...[], arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Where can I read more about the syntax of `[,,,,,]` and what it means?

Comment: that will just returns an array with undefined elements, ie.
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]

Comment: @silkfire this is called spread operator

Comment: @silkfire [Grammar and types - Array Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) see the "Extra commas in array literals" section.

Comment: My personal preference: `foo(...[,,,,,"f"])`. Or just refactoring the code to never have functions with that many optional arguments in the first place.

Comment: I would like to explain this for future readers: First, `Array(n)` creates an Array of length `n` with undefined items (see next parenthesis), or `[,,,,,]` creates an array containing five `undefined` items (technically not, but close enough). The spec states that at most one trailing comma is ignored, and missing expressions are replaced with undefined (see previous parenthesis). Then, the `...` operator spreads out the items of the array into arguments. (Edited for slight elaboration)

Answer (score 25):

You *could* use `apply`:

```
foo.apply(this, Array(5).concat([theFValue]));
```

In this case, `5` is the amount of parameters you want to skip.

Wrap that in a function:

```
function call(fn, skipParams, parameter) {
    fn.apply(this, Array(skipParams).concat([parameter]));
}

call(foo, 5, theFValue);
```

However, in that case the scope of `this` is different, so you may need to pass that, too:

```
function call(fn, skipParams, parameter, thisArg) {
    fn.apply(thisArg, Array(skipParams).concat([parameter]));
}

call(foo, 5, theFValue, this);
```

Then again, this implementation only allows 1 parameter to be passed. Let's improve that:

```
function call(fn, skipParams, parameters, thisArg) {
    fn.apply(thisArg, Array(skipParams).concat(parameters));
}

call(foo, 5, [theFValue, theGValue, theHValue], this);
```

That's starting to get a "little" verbose. It also doesn't handle missing parameters after the first parameter that well, unless you want to pass `undefined`:

```
call(foo, 5, [theFValue, theGValue, theHValue, undefined, theJValue], this);
```

---

Or, something completely different:

```
var _ = undefined;
foo(_,_,_,_,_, theFValue);
```

---

**On a more serious note:**

Your best option to deal with optional parameters, is to change the way you're handling parameters. Simply pass an object:

```
function foo(parameters){
    // do stuff with `parameters.a`, `parameters.b`, etc.
}

foo({c: 1, g: false});
```

This approach doesn't suffer from *any* of the drawbacks in the earlier examples.

Comment: More simple would be `foo.apply(this, [,,,,,theFValue])`. Nice idea with the wrapping function, but it would slightly classier to make that a HOF which takes just `fn` and `skipParams` as arguments and returns a function that can be called with `parameter`.

Comment: Then the amount of parameters skipped isn't variable.

Comment: ideally the call should be `foo(f: false)`, like in C#... perhaps will be possible in the future...?! )

Comment: Something like that [is possible in ES6](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-default-argument.html), @Serge.

Comment: @Cerbrus: the link is about default arguments, not exactly about optional or named arguments that could be skipped...

Comment: Automatically skip parameters that are not actually used by the function

Comment: BTW: If `var _ = undefined; foo(_,_,_,_,_, theFValue);` solution was a separate answer, I would upvote it. As it is, it is buried in a long answer, most of which I don't feel inclined to upvote.

Answer (score 24):

A better way to deal with optional arguments is to pass an object whose attributes you look up:

```
function foo(options) {
    var a = options.a,
        b = options.b,
        c = options.c,
        d = options.d,
        e = options.e,
        f = options.f;
}

foo({ f: 15 });
```

Comment: The object approach is the least verbose (the `var` stuff is optional) and most flexible one.

Comment: the only minor note is that the users should be aware about the parameter internal names "a, b, c" etc, that is not "visible" in say, intellisense helper...

Comment: Some might want to check if the argument is actual object: `if (typeof options !== 'object') throw new Error('INVALID_TYPE: options is not "object"');`

Comment: Note, it would be cleaner to use object destructuring here:
`const {a, b, c, d, e, f} = options`

Comment: @serge You can document the parameters so intellisense is aware. `@param {Object} params` then `@param {number} params.f - Number representing ...`

Comment: @3limin4t0r could you elaborate in an answer? )

Comment: @serge See the JSDoc documentation: https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html Most intellisense helpers pick up JSDoc and provide it to you while coding.

Comment: It would be even cleaner to do the object destructuring like so: `function foo({a, b, c, d, e, f}) {`

Answer (score 10):

Skip function:

```
const skip = (num) => new Array(num);
```

Skipping beginning params:

```
foo(...skip(4), f);
```

Skipping end params:

```
foo(f, ...skip(4));
```

Skipping middle params:

```
foo(f, ...skip(4), f2);
```

Comment: BTW, "Skipping end params" is not needed. `foo(f)` works in JS - params missing at end are `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

If you will pass an object with a property name **f** so you can use [destructuring assignment](http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingDeepMatching) with ES6 syntax like this:

```js
function foo({ f }) {
  console.log(f);
}
    
foo({ g: 5, f: 10 });
```

Comment: Keep in mind that from this moment you cannot call function without parameters i.e. `foo()`, you must now call it `foo({})`.

Comment: As @AlexG.P. mentioned: you should change `({ f })` to `({ f } = {}}` in order to omit the error occuring when `foo()` is invoked.

Answer (score 4):

I provide some methods that may help you achieve, as below,

1. [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (recommend)
2. [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

---

### Method1: [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

#### Example1

```js
function Person(name, {id="007", age=-1, info={msg:null, mood:undefined}}) {
  return [name, id, age, info.msg, info.mood]
}

//  Test Only
for (const [result, expected] of [
  [Person("Carson", {}), // If you don't need any options then must set "" or {}
    ["Carson", "007", -1, null, undefined]
  ],
  [Person("Aoo", {
    age: 29,
    info: {
      msg: "hello world"
    }
  }),
    ["Aoo", "007", 29, "hello world", undefined]
  ],
  [Person("Boo", {
    id: "003",
    info: {
      mood: "Happy"
    }
  }),
    ["Boo", "003", -1, null, "Happy"]
  ]
]) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(expected))
}
```

#### Example 2

```js
const user = {
  id: 42,
  displayName: 'jdoe',
  fullName: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
  }
};

function userId({id}) {
  return id;
}

function whois({displayName, fullName: {firstName: name}}) {
  return `${displayName} is ${name}`;
}

console.log(userId(user)); // 42
console.log(whois(user));  // "jdoe is John"
```

source code from [object_destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) <sup>search `Unpacking fields from objects passed as a function parameter`</sup>

### Method2

Use [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to set the default value

```js
const val = obj ?? "default value" // if obj is undefined then val = default value
const val = obj?.msg // equal to obj.msg if {msg:...} exists in the obj. Otherwise, undefined
```

for example

```
/*
Assume your options is:
{
  id:"",
  info:{
    msg:"",
    mood: "",
  }
}
*/
function MyFunc(name, options = {}) {
  const id = options.id ?? "007"
  const msg = options.info?.msg ?? null
  const mood = options.info?.mood
  // ...
}
```

#### Example

```js
function Person(name, options = {}) {
  const id = options.id ?? "007"
  const msg = options.info?.msg ?? null
  const mood = options.info?.mood
  return [name, id, msg, mood]
}


for (const [result, expected] of [
  [Person("Carson"),
    ["Carson", "007", null, undefined]
  ],
  [Person("Aoo", {
    info: {
      msg: "hello world"
    }
  }),
    ["Aoo", "007", "hello world", undefined]
  ],
  [Person("Boo", {
    id: "003",
    info: {
      mood: "Happy"
    }
  }),
    ["Boo", "003", null, "Happy"]
  ]
]) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(expected))
}
```

#### Method 2.extend

If you want the IDE to know what the options is, you may consider using the below method,

```js
function PersonOptions(options={}) {
  this.id = options.id ?? "007"
  this.msg = options.info?.msg ?? null
  this.mood = options.info?.mood
}

function Person2(name, options = new PersonOptions()) {
  return [name, options.id, options.msg, options.mood]
}

for (const [result, expected] of [
  [Person2("Carson"),
    ["Carson", "007", null, undefined]
  ],
  [Person2("Aoo", new PersonOptions({
    info: {
      msg: "hello world"
    }
  })),
    ["Aoo", "007", "hello world", undefined]
  ],
  [Person2("Boo", new PersonOptions({
    id: "003",
    info: {
      mood: "Happy"
    }
  })),
    ["Boo", "003", null, "Happy"]
  ]
]) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(expected))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is something you're going to want to do often, then consider a simple wrapper:

```
function bar(f) {
    foo(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, f);
}
```

If you're only doing this once, or you're wanting a random permutation of the parameters then this approach isn't the best.

Answer (score 1):

Use bind for a partial application:

```js
function foo(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    document.write(f);
}

function skip(f, n) {
    while (n--) {
        f = f.bind(null, undefined);
    }
    return f;
}

skip(foo, 5)('hallo');
```

Comment: compare my "ideal" readability: `draw(height: 5)` vs `skip(draw, 5)(5)`

Comment: it is not valid javascript. what do you mean with that?

Comment: I mean your skip works, but it has a bad readability. For someone did't code is hard to understand what the code does. The called function is "skip", when should be "draw"

Comment: well, it works. any other presented solutions has not better readability nor functionality. should i delete my answer?

Comment: no, thank you for your answer. Is good, but I find the sookie's answer has a little bit better readability: the foo function is directly called...

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
function multiply(a = 2, b = 1) {
  return a * b;
}

console.log(multiply(undefined, 3));
// expected output: 6
```

If you pass a param undefined, it will use the default value from the definition.

Comment: The question shows use of `undefined`, and asks for *a less verbose* way to write that.