# Skip arguments in a TypeScript function

Tags: angular, typescript, function, arguments, spread

I have tried the [answer of Pacerier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622678/7942242) from the question [Skip arguments in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518615/skip-arguments-in-a-javascript-function). But it does not seem to work.

I have a function with many arguments

```
this.service.list("all",null, null, localStorage.getItem('currentProgram'), null, 100, ...Array(2), environment.liveMode).subscribe(...)
```

The only way I've found is to write it one by one, like (,null, null or undefined,undefined).

I also set a test method to see if it was different, but it does not work as well.

```
test(a: any, b: any, c: any, d: string) {
    console.log(d)
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.test(...Array(3), "a")
}
```

I also tried other syntax proposed in the answer.

Is there a less verbose way to do this in TypeScript ?

Comment: Your function has a lot of optional arguments, this could be seen as a code smell. If you can refactor the function then you should take an object instead of multiple arguments like `function foo(options: {a?: string, b?: number})`.

Answer (score 2):

In TypeScript if you want to skip a parameter you're obliged to explicitly pass `undefined` or `null` as the parameter value. Example:

```
function f(param1?: string, param2?: number, param3?: boolean) {
// do something
}

f(,,true); // ❌ Error
f(...[,,], true); // ❌ Error
f(...Array(2), true); // ❌ Error
f(undefined, undefined, true); // ✅ Works 
f(null, null, true); // ✅ Works
```

You can find more information and examples in this section of the TypeScript documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters

Comment: @crg I could see that, I just described to you a few possible options.