Skipping parameter use in a function once called
I have the below function:
function makeAnimal(
    animal: string,
    color: string,
    age: number = 3,
    gender: string = 'male'
    name: string = 'Barky'
){
 // some code
}

When I call this function, I do:
console.log(makeAnimal(
    'dog',
    'black'
    3,
    'male',
    'Marky'
))

Is there an easier / cleaner way to call this function where I will just provide animal, color and name and no longer manually needing to provide age and gender?

You can explicitly pass undefined, if that's what you mean? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32518615/3001761 But it's much neater to use object destructuring (then you get "named parameters" too).

This is exactly what I needed thanks.

The idiomatic way is to introduce a parameter object. That gives you cheap "named parameters" and allows you to pass them in any order or omit any of them. Passing undefined to get the default value works but it very quickly becomes unwieldy. That's basically the situation you're in right now makeAnimal('dog', 'black', 3, undefined, 'Marky') is hard to read and understand. Moreover, it's very easy to swap arguments by accident: makeAnimal('black', 'dog', ...) is still a valid call and it looks OK. You have to verify it against the parameters in the signature.

You can reorder function arguments this way:
function makeAnimal(
    animal: string,
    color: string,
    name: string = 'Barky'
    age: number = 3,
    gender: string = 'male'
){
 // some code
}
makeAnimal("Dog", "Brown", "Marky"); // should work


Already thought of this, the problem is the function is already being used everywhere, so I needed to add the gender parameter and not hurt other code locations its being used.

In that case i think the first comment solved the problem for you.
